# Solving separable differential equations via partial fractions: $\frac{dy}{dx} = y(y-1)$

Tags: calculus, integration, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

> Solve $\frac{dy}{dx} = y(y-1)$.

I got

$$\frac{dy}{y(y-1)} = dx \implies \ln|y-1| - \ln|y| = x + c$$

$$\implies \ln \bigg| \frac{y - 1}{y}\bigg| = x + c$$

$$\implies 1 - \frac{1}{y} = Ce^{x}$$

$$\implies y = \frac{1}{1 - Ce^{x}}$$

However, [Wolfram|Alpha](http://m.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve%20dy%2Fdx%20%3D%20%28y-1%29y&x=0&y=0) seems to disagree with this. Can anyone point out my mistake?

Comment: It often gives better readable results if you explicitly add `y'(0)=a` to the request at WA, http://m.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve+dy%2Fdx+%3D+%28y-1%29y%2C+y%280%29%3Da

Answer (score 2):

You have not made any mistake. Let's start from Wolfram's solution:
$$\begin{align} y(x)&=\frac{1}{e^{c_1+x}+1} \\&=\frac{1}{e^{c_1}\cdot e^x+1}\end{align}$$
Here's the important part: Note that $c_1$ is an *arbitrary* constant, so we can let $C:=-e^{c_1}$ to obtain your solution.

Comment: you can also just generalize $e^{c_1}$ to $c_2$

Answer (score 1):

Notice that you removed the absolute value so instead
$$\left|\frac{y-1}{y}\right|=Ce^x$$
Here $C>0$ but if you drop the absolute value then $C$ can also be negative as
$$\frac{y-1}{y}=\pm Ce^x=C_1e^x$$
Here $C_1$ can be both positive and negative.

Comment: @projectilemotion Yeah,you're probably right,though just in case I posted this to complement your answer,you explained the how and I the why (well at least that's how i perceived it)

Comment: I agree with your perception, and this is certainly useful to the OP to explain the transition between his/her 3rd step to the 4th. (+1)

Answer (score 0):

$$y=\frac1{1-Ce^x},$$

then

$$y'=-\frac{-Ce^x}{(1-Ce^x)^2}$$

and

$$y(y-1)=\frac1{1-Ce^x}\frac{1-1+Ce^x}{1-Ce^x}.$$

You made no mistake.

Comment: By the way your solution is a little more elegant, as WA's solution can require a complex constant.